# How to connect to a remote IIS with INETMGR on WIndows 7

Tags: iis, windows-7

I can't seem to find any way to connect to a remote IIS instance with my local INETMGR on my Windows 7 machine. It shows my settings for my local IIS and everything I've tried from clicking various places on the connections panel, changing the address in the address bar and checking the various menubar menus none seem to offer connect to another machine.

Comment: What version of IIS are you trying to connect to?

Comment: 7.5, but the real issue is can't find any connect to... type functionality in INETMGR on Win7 at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't believe this is an easy a process as it used to be.

If you just install the IIS Manager from 'Add/Remove Programs' > 'Turn Windows Features on or off' you will not see the toolbar controls that allow you to connect to a remote server.

Instead, you will need to download the IIS Mangaer for Remote Administration from the IIS site:

http://www.iis.net/download/IISManager

Comment: You may also need to add the *Management Service* Role Service to the target computer, and enable Remote Connections through that service (via InetMgr, server level Remote Management icon).

Comment: Please beware that IIS remote management is not supported on client Windows (Desktop) operating systems. Please see - [Web Platform and IIS CAN'T FIND MANAGEMENT SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34118084/465053) & [Is it possible to enable the IIS remote management icons in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/q/1131098/374397)

Comment: There's an addin for IIS Manager called IIS Manager for Remote Administration 1.2 that solves this https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41177

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to connect to IIS7, you need to configure it to allow remote management connections.

Comment: This wasn't the real issue but your answer here did make it alot quicker after I downloaded IISManager and got connection denied.

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: MSDN Documentation is very helpful for [configuring Remote Connections in IIS Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/remote-administration/configuring-remote-administration-and-feature-delegation-in-iis-7#configuring-remote-connections-in-iis-manager)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use "Computer Management" in Administrative Tools, then under Action: Connect to another computer...

After connecting to the computer you want to manage, you can use the IIS manager under Services and Applications.